# Could not run Configuration Admin on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, osgi, apache-felix, equinox, declarative-services

I am trying to use Configuration Admin to pass configuration info to a bundle. 
I am using declarative services based on Equinox implementation of OSGI. First of all since I couldn't find the Equinox implementation of Config Admin I have installed the felix implementation so it would be great if someone have suggestion of where I could get the equinox version.

My main question is: I keep getting the following error when ever I run the program. It seems like a null 'configuration' object is being passed to my update methode.

```
osgi> !SESSION 2014-08-10 06:54:09.862 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -dev file:C:/Users/Desktop/OSGI/eclipseee/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/configurator/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog -console

!ENTRY org.apache.felix.configadmin 4 0 2014-08-10 07:09:52.639
!MESSAGE Cannot use configuration de.services.logger.mtinylogger for   [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService, id=33, bundle=11/initial@reference:file:../workspace1/de.services.logger.mtinylogger/]: No visibility to configuration bound to initial@reference:file:../workspace1/de.init.configurator/
```

I have made a configurator bundle that creates the configuration object and the main content in it's activate method (called by declarative services) is:

```
    protected void activate(BundleContext bundleContext) throws IOException
    {
    //Retrieve a reference to the Configuration Admin service
    ServiceReference serviceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference(ConfigurationAdmin.class.getName());  
    if(serviceReference != null)
    {
        ConfigurationAdmin configAdmin = (ConfigurationAdmin) bundleContext.getService(serviceReference);

        if(configAdmin != null)
        {
        Configuration configuration = configAdmin.getConfiguration("de.services.logger.mtinylogger");

        //Update configuration object
        Dictionary<String, Object> configProperties = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        configProperties.put("port", 8080);

        configuration.update(configProperties);  
     }
```

And the updated method inside the bundle implementing managedServices is as follows:

```
    @Override
@SuppressWarnings( { "rawtypes", "unchecked" } )
public void updated( Dictionary configuration ) throws ConfigurationException
{

    if( configuration != null ) {

        System.out.println(configuration.get("port"));
    }
    else
        System.out.println("configuration is equal to 'null ");
}
```

The strange thing is, when I stop and start the bundle being updated, it always displays' the configuration is equal to null' as if I have not already created the configuration object. What am I missing here?? I have spent almost 2 weeks trying to solve the issues with running configuration admin but it's taking too munch of my time. I would really appreciate some info about this. txs!!

Edited:
Here I have added the 'activate' method of the class registering the ManagedService.

```
    protected void activate( BundleContext ctx )
{
    Dictionary< String, Object > properties = new Hashtable< String, Object >();

    //properties.put( Constants.SERVICE_PID, ctx.getBundle().getSymbolicName() );//optionally
    properties.put( Constants.SERVICE_PID, "de.services.logger.mtinylogger" );

    mService = ctx.registerService( ManagedService.class.getName(), this, properties );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is not that you are using the Felix bundle on Equinox. OSGi bundles that follow the standard can be used on any framework implementation.

Your problem is that you are using the "wrong" method to create the configuration:

```
configAdmin.getConfiguration("de.services.logger.mtinylogger");
```

The problem is that this method will implicitly "bind" the configuration to this bundle (the configurator), therefore the bundle that this configuration really is for will no longer see it. In short, replace your method with this one:

```
configAdmin.getConfiguration("de.services.logger.mtinylogger", null);
```

That way, the configuration is not bound, and will be available for the intended target.

My explanation about binding is relatively short, the OSGi specification (freely available) addresses it in greater detail.

Comment: I have added 'null' as you suggested but I am still getting the exact same result. In case it helps I have added the code of my activate class where I register the managedService at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Did you clear the bundle cache before trying my suggestion. If not, the old configuration might still be in there.

Comment: Also, your activator seems to depend on Configuration Admin being started before this bundle. If not, no configuration will obviously be set. I suggest you look into using one of the dependency management solutions out there. As the author of the Apache Felix Dependency Manager, I obviously can recommend that one, but the OSGi specification also provides Declarative Services, which works just fine for your code too.

Comment: Thank you very much it works now. I am not sure what you meant about the dependency management but I am already using declarative services. I still need to make sure the start level of the Configuration Admin is higher than the others so that it'll be started first. That's the approach I am following now. (By the way I'm now posting another question about an error I get in the logfile whenever I start OSGI from the console maybe you could help me on that aswell

Comment: Depending on start levels is in general a very dangerous thing to do. I've written a blog to explain: http://www.planetmarrs.net/start-levels-in-osgi/